# How to a read a string value after post response with fetch api

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to get the response and be able to read the value of the post it returns either as null or has data to verify the post before moving on to the next section, I am using the fetch api method I got the response and got it working with the form but I cant get the javascript to read if the response is null or not but got it on the console. Here is the code.

```
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Origin", "*");
      

      
  var acct = JSON.stringify({"acct":account});
     

  var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: acct,
      //credentials: "include",
      redirect: 'follow'
  };

  const doAjax = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://myrestapi', requestOptions);
      if (response.ok) {
      
          const aVal = await response.text();

          return Promise.resolve(aVal);
          //return aVal;
      }
      else
      {
        return Promise.reject('*** PHP file not found');
      }
  }


  function postData() {
    if(response => response == null){
      console.log("I am Null ");
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("I am ALIIIIIIVE ");
    }

  }

  doAjax()
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .finally(response => postData())
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error + account));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to pass the response to `postData` like this:

```js
function postData(response) {
  if(response === null) {
    console.log("I am Null ");
  } else {
    console.log("I am ALIIIIIIVE ");
  }
}

doAjax()
  .then(response => postData(response))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error + account));
```

Comment: Thank you. Super close I just cant kick the conditional in. Always defaulting to the else statement "I am alive" even when the account is null :(.

Comment: @Btru What happens when you `console.log` the response in `postData`? I doubt it's actually null if it's printing from the else statement.

Comment: I just read an article relating to what you said I think about it actually being null but more or less a null string of some sort from the api,if I change if(response == null) to if(response.length == 4) to compare the length of null seems to have kicked in. Not sure if this is good practice but seems to have worked at least as a temporary solution. :) Thank-you.